# How do make layout in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, layout

I am trying to make an activity which should look like the following:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k78Cl.png)

The problem is that it does not get the same when I start the app. The buttons are cut or the text is cut. And if I change the position of one button, everything gets in the upper-left-corner.
My question is: What do I have to do that everything gets the position I want?
I used a Relative Layout. Maybe this is the problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="245dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="83dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="83dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="238dp"
        android:text="Info"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="245dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Kartenansicht"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="115dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="71dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="73dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:text="Um zu überprüfen, ob Sicherheitskameras in der Nähe sind, bitte hier drücken:"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="83dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="84dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="Start"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: 1. Setting a fixed HEIGHT for Buttons will result in bad behaviours (cropped text as the main one) many times. Use WRAP_CONTENT instead.
 2. RelativeLayout is "obsolete" and was replaced by newer ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 0):

You have a big mess in your layout. For example:

```
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

These 2 parameters can't co-exist.
For your desired layout you should use LinearLayout with Orientation set to vertical. That way, all you'll need to do is write your UI objects 1 below the other and they will be placed 1 above the other. To center them, you can then use gravity and layout_gravity

```
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
```

And that should be all.

Edit:
Just for you to know, Relative layout basically places any given object at position 0,0 of the layout. If you create few objects, they will be placed one on top of the other.

Answer (score 0):

use the constraintlayout and for example you give each view a constraint of start and end after you can set the width to 0dp

Comment: I converted into Constraint Layout and now everything is placed in the upper-left corner

Comment: Ok now I got it. I had to add the constraints. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to create the design by dragging and dropping then it would be better to use constraint layout instead of relative layout, but if you like to use relative layout anyway, you should use **"centerInParent = "true"** "in the middle button and set **"layout_above = "@+id/your_centered_view_id"** for the above button and **"layout_below = "@+id/your_centered_view_id"** ".